# Project Inexplicably lagging for no reason

Tags: c, opengl, glut

```
#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h> 
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1415926535
#define DR 0.0174533 //or degrees to radians

float CameraX, CameraY, CameraDeltaX, CameraDeltaY, CameraAngle = 0;
int Mapx = 8; Mapy = 8;
int map[8][8] =
{
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};
typedef struct
{
    int w, a, d, s;                     //button state on off
}ButtonKeys; ButtonKeys Keys;
void drawMinimap()
{
    int x, y, xo, yo;
    for (y = 0;y < Mapy;y++)
    {
        for (x = 0;x < Mapx;x++)
        {
            if (map[x][y] == 1) { glColor3f(1, 1, 1); }
            else { glColor3f(0, 0, 0); }
            xo = x * 10; yo = y * 10;
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2i(0 + xo + 1, 0 + yo + 1);
            glVertex2i(0 + xo + 1, 10 + yo - 1);
            glVertex2i(10 + xo - 1, 10 + yo - 1);
            glVertex2i(10 + xo - 1, 0 + yo + 1);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
    glPointSize(3);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(CameraX * 10, CameraY * 10);
    glEnd();
    glLineWidth(1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(CameraX * 10, CameraY * 10);
    glVertex2i(CameraX * 10 + CameraDeltaX * 2, CameraY * 10 + CameraDeltaY * 2);
    glEnd();
}
void Draw3dWorldUsingRC()
{
    int mx = 0, my = 0, dof = 0, side; float rx, ry, ra, disX, disY;
    ra = CameraAngle - DR * 48;
    for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++)
    {
        int hit = 0;
        side = 0;
        rx = CameraX;
        ry = CameraY;
        disX = 0;
        disY = 0;
        dof = 0;
        while (hit == 0)
        {
            if (side == 1)
            {
                rx += cos(ra) * 0.1;
                disX += 0.1;
                side = 0;
                dof += 0.1;
            }
            else
            {
                ry += sin(ra) * 0.1;
                disY += 0.1;
                side = 1;
                dof += 0.1;
            }
            if (map[(int)floor(rx)][(int)floor(ry)] != 0)
            {
                hit = 1;
            }
        }
        float ca = CameraAngle - ra; if (ca < 0) { ca += 2 * PI; } if (ca > 2*PI) { ca -= 2 * PI; }
        float lineheight = 90;
        if (side == 1)
        {
            disX = disX * cos(ca);
            glColor3f(0, 1, 0);glLineWidth(2); glBegin(GL_LINES); glVertex2i(100 + i * 2, lineheight - lineheight / disX); glVertex2i(100 + i * 2, lineheight + lineheight/disX); glEnd();
        }
        else
        {
            disY = disY * cos(ca);
            glColor3f(0, 0.8, 0);glLineWidth(2); glBegin(GL_LINES); glVertex2i(100 + i * 2, lineheight - lineheight / disY); glVertex2i(100 + i * 2, lineheight + lineheight/ disY); glEnd();
        }
        glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);glLineWidth(2); glBegin(GL_LINES); glVertex2i(CameraX*10, CameraY * 10); glVertex2i(rx * 10, ry * 10); glEnd();
        ra += DR;
    }
}
float frame1, frame2, fps, smoothing;
void controls(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 'a') { Keys.a = 1; }
    if (key == 'd') { Keys.d = 1; }
    if (key == 'w') { Keys.w = 1; }
    if (key == 's') { Keys.s = 1; }
}
void controlsup(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 'a') { Keys.a = 0; }
    if (key == 'd') { Keys.d = 0; }
    if (key == 'w') { Keys.w = 0; }
    if (key == 's') { Keys.s = 0; }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void display()
{
    frame2 = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME); fps = (frame2 - frame1); frame1 = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    if (Keys.w == 1) { CameraX += cos(CameraAngle) * fps; CameraY += sin(CameraAngle) * fps;}
    if (Keys.s == 1) { CameraX -= cos(CameraAngle) * fps; CameraY -= sin(CameraAngle) * fps;}
    if (Keys.d == 1) { CameraX += CameraAngle * DR * 5 * fps;}
    if (Keys.a == 1) { CameraX -= CameraAngle * DR * 5 * fps;}
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawMinimap();
    Draw3dWorldUsingRC();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0);
    gluOrtho2D(0, 280, 180, 0);
    CameraX = 4; CameraY = 4;
    CameraDeltaX = cos(CameraAngle) * 5; CameraDeltaY = sin(CameraAngle) * 5;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(280, 180);
    glutCreateWindow("Neptune Engine Alpha 1");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    glutKeyboardFunc(controls);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(controlsup);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Today I was working on my project and it suddenly started acting like a slide show could anybody help me solve what is happening? I've switched to visual studio 2019 and it is only affecting the actual project window. I was trying to make the movement smoother. I don't seem to be getting any errors and I can move and scale the window freely without any lag. Could somebody help me please?

UPDATE: I solved this recently I just don't know how to close this question.

Comment: How frequently are you calling `glutPostRedisplay`? It appears you respond to keyboard input and not a timer.

Comment: @Neil is that a bad thing I'm new to using open gl

Comment: As far as I can see, you only redraw when a key is released. So basically the number of frames per second depends on how often you release a key. If you want to keep the camera turning while the key is pressed, then you have to render more often.

Comment: @BDL so should I put it in the main loop?

Comment: Oh wait I did it works now thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the comments, you have to render more. You can do this by calling `glutPostRedisplay` immediately after it's done displaying, but this will probably run at 100% CPU speed and will tie up your rendering with your engine speed. A slightly more nuanced way is to even out the rendering by registering a `glutTimerFunc` for periodic updates. In the timer function, call `glutPostRedisplay` and `glutTimerFunc` again.

```
static void update(int zero) {
    (void *)zero;
    glutTimerFunc(20 /* 50 fps */, &update, 0);
    /* TODO: Advance your engine;
     _ie_ move some stuff that doesn't really
     `display` in here. */
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

You've done a `glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)`, which should be there as well, because [glutTimerFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html), "GLUT attempts to deliver the timer callback as soon as possible after the expiration of the callback's time interval," which, I take it, is not really very accurate at keeping absolute time.

Comment: Thanks I solved this a while ago I just put it in my main render loop!

Comment: I just don't know how to close the question

Comment: You can also answer your own question, write what you did that worked, that way people searching for this problem will see how you solved it; I think you can accept your own answer no matter what rep you are at, just click the check.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed the problem was that I put my Redisplay at the end of the display function.